# Is it possible to center an array of objects without dynamically changing the style?

Tags: css

I run into this problem a lot when making grids of thumbnails, etc.  When you try to center using `margin: auto;`

Normally, I will just use PHP and a counter to style the last object in each row without a margin on the right. But this is somewhat complicated, and I was *hoping* there might be a simpler way to do it using a CSS trick or something.

I've whipped up a stupid little example of the problem here http://jsfiddle.net/convoke/kFzg5/27/

And here's what I'd like it to look like http://jsfiddle.net/convoke/NZR9X/3/

Subtle difference to the centering of the parent object, but hopefully you see what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced floats to inline-blocks + justified "text":

http://jsfiddle.net/kFzg5/28/

Warning: older browsers does not love this technique, and the last row looks fugly.

Second "solution" with extra wrapper div and much `overflow: hidden`:

http://jsfiddle.net/kFzg5/29/

Comment: Interesting.  Second solution is looking pretty good to me.  Well played.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435636/faking-collapsed-left-right-margins-in-css

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZGWHT/

Use td + td to target a td if there is a td to the left of it (ignores the first td).

Comment: That's cool.  What exactly does `td + td` mean?  Like, semantically?

Comment: It's called an adjacent sibling selector.

Answer (score 0):

you could center then offset the parent container with a negative left margin, margin-left:-10px and then set your image containers to margin:0 0 10px 10px.